# Who is to blame?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

I think I should use "*whom* is to blame" but I don't know.

In speech I'd probably say "who's to blame?" implying "who is" but that just doesn't sound quite right to me.

Comment: Resist the impulse to use _whom_. Anywhere. Certainly not as the subject of _is to blame_.

Comment: If a credible answer to a ***who/whom*** question is ***Him***, you could at least *consider* using ***whom***. But apart from "fixed expression" forms such as *To whom it may concern* or *For whom the bell tolls* (preceding preposition), @John Lawler's advice is really all you need.

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with "Who's to blame?". That's what I would say. I think the answer to "Who's to blame?" is "He is!" and not "Him", which is again what I would expect the response to me if I were to ask this question. Actually, the expected response to "Who's to blame?" would be "That guy!".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Whom is to blame?* is wrong, from what I can tell.

*Whom* is a pronoun that may only serve as the object in a sentence (be it affirmative or interrogative), and as such it cannot be used in a sentence where no subject is stated, or at the very least, implied. Your question should read:

*Whom are we to blame?*

or

*Whom should we blame?*

(*we*, in both cases, being the subject).

As [deadrat](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/125330/deadrat) has noted in his comment below, *whom* may very well appear in an imperative clause, where the subject is not explicitly stated, but rather implied, such as:

*Blame whom you like.*

As for your instinctive choice *Who is to blame*, the issue here is not the opening question word, but the voice of the infinitive (*"to blame"*), 'cause whoever he/she is, Mr. Who is not the one blaming but the one being blamed, so if one prioritized *semantical transparency*, as [Janus Bahs Jacquet](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/47827/janus-bahs-jacquet) puts it, the question should read:

*Who is to be blamed?*

*Who is to blame?* is not, however, wrong. It's merely idiomatic.

*To blame* has virtually come to serve as a synonym for *"blameable"* (see [Janus Bahs Jacquet](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/47827/janus-bahs-jacquet)'s comment for a more refined description), while the subject of the infinitive (i.e. those blaming), is left to the realm of the implicit, so to speak, and thus rid of its significance.

Yet another alternative, almost identical to the last one, but less confusing perhaps, is:

*Who is there to blame?*

---

Addendum: Thanks to both aforementioned members for their constructive criticism of my initial answer.

Comment: “Who is to blame?” doesn't imply that that _who_ will be doing the blaming. _To blame_ is simply an idiomatic, if not exactly logical, pseudo-adjectival collocation that means ‘blameable’. The wording “Who is to blame?” is far more idiomatic than “Who is to be blamed?”, so saying that it ‘should’ be the latter makes very little sense. It would be more semantically transparent if it were the latter, but language is not always semantically transparent.

Comment: There's a good answer lurking in there somewhere. Tighten this up a bit. *Whom* may serve only as the object **in** a sentence. Sentences don't have objects; certain syntactic elements do. This sentence has a stated subject, namely *who*, and *whom* may certainly appear in sentences with no stated subject: *Kill **whom** you like*. There is no voice for the finite verb in the sentence; you may mean that the infinitive could be active (*to blame*) or passive (*to be blamed*). The latter isn't a *should* but a *could*, for reasons of idiom as JBJ points out. [con't]->

Comment: <-[con't] I think you've put your finger on one cause of the OP's unease: that the semantic receiver of the blame is the subject, and you've given two nice transpositions to *whom*. I think there's an additional element of hypercorrection, i.e., the OP may have been repeatedly warned to use *whom* in sentences like *Whom did you talk to?*, where *who* is rapidly becoming acceptable (as JL implies above) if it's not already there.

Comment: +1. I'd agree with the idiomatic origin but would love to see if there exists some authoritative reference!

Answer (score 2):

The correct choice would be,

> Who is to blame?

The word *who* is the subject of the verb, not the object. In fact, the verb *to be* is a **linking verb**, as are all forms of *to be*, meaning that they don't take objects, but rather re-describe the subject with a subject complement.

When it comes to linking verbs, you should always use *who*, not *whom*. But with an action verb, like *hit*, it would be correct to use *whom*. For example,

> Whom did Alex hit with the rock?

Here, the subject of the verb is *Alex*, and *whom* is the object. This a correct use of *whom*.